# How to enlarge the status bar font size?

Tags: font, macos

Can the status bar font be enlarged? Is this size hard-wired and unique? Is there any other (configurable) font size anywhere which could correspond to this one on user space?

Some time ago, I asked how to configure the status bar ([How to configure the status bar?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/159883/how-to-configure-the-status-bar)). The answer was that it couldn't be done. I sent that as a feature request to Apple. They didn't answer (of course) so I thought that, maybe, that font could be *linked* to some other one (for instance, though this is not the case to the one on `View Options`on the Finder.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to configure the status bar?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/159883/how-to-configure-the-status-bar)

Comment: @Tetsujin, more than a duplicate, it tried to be a refinement (notice that this one refers to that) or a continuation on a slightly different bias. Nevertheless, if you think it would be better placed under that older question , please, move it there!

Comment: You mean the menu bar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is actually an easy fix for this, as it turns out.

Abilitynet.org has a nice clear description at https://mcmw.abilitynet.org.uk/apple-os-x-10-10-yosemite-making-text-larger/

I didn't discover that source until after I'd called Apple Support, where I was given the same very simple answer, which is:

On the Apple Menu, go to System Preferences.  In System Preferences, go to Displays.  Change from Default to Scaled, then click the box to the left of the Default box to choose larger font or gigantic font.  (Unfortunately, the Scaled display options are not available with a slider, which would have been perfect as then you could choose exactly the size that works best for you.  However, the next size up from Default will probably work well for almost anyone who's been struggling to read the menu bar.)

Making this change not only fixes the visibility of the menu bar, but also carries over to other application menus.  For example, I use WORD, and was having to peer at my 27-inch screen from 2 inches away to see where to navigate the cursor in order to change the font size for my document.  In Google, if I wanted to read an url, I had to copy and paste it into WORD, then zoom the text display. It was VERY frustrating, and now all of that's just a bad dream.

((As an aside, as a "newbie" to the Apple world, this was my first contact with Apple Support and they earned top marks from me for response time, courtesy, and giving me precisely the info I needed.  Thank you Apple Support!)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Heck of a first answer - Thanks!

Comment: @BettyG07 My Display preferences don't look exactly like yours (I'm running OSX 10.10.5) but your hint was enough to get me there: I changed the text size to the largest one and now I can read on my 27" screen without risking my eyesight or bumping my head on the monitor. BTW, as you said, it works on the display as a whole (all the text is affected by the change).

Answer (score 0):

Nothing has changed in that area in last 4 weeks since you asked, so changing the font size in the Menu bar is currently not possible.

If you are like me (hate the to small fonts) your only "work around" I know is to change the screen resolution.

That will unfortunately change all of the screen not just the menu bar, but at least now I can read it without squirting.

Reduce the screen resolution to next lower number where it still suits all your needs, while the font becomes larger at same time.

If you find your self switching the resolution often then a $4 app called [Quickres](http://www.quickresapp.com/) might help you.